# Trying to get Leaflet Map to change map view to selected country option

Tags: javascript, jquery, curl

I have a `<select>` list populated with a bunch of country names. When an option is selected, the `value` attribute (the ISO of the country) of the `<option>` element is used in a PHP cURL routine to search through a JSON file to return a latlng of the country capital. I want this latlng info to then adjust the map accordingly, in other words, set the view to the country selected.

getPHP.js:

```
$('#countrySearch').click(function() {
    console.log("Button clicked");
    $.ajax({
        url: "libs/php/getCountryISO.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            iso: $('#countrySelect option:selected').val()
        },
        success: function(result) {

            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
            console.log("JSON stringified");

            if (result.status.name == "ok") {

                console.log("All recieved well.");
                $(mymap).setView(result['data']['latlng']);

            }
        
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR);
        }
    })
});
```

script.js:

```
//Loading Map
var mymap = L.map('mapid').locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16}); //Set Location to Users Location
      L.tileLayer('https://tile.jawg.io/jawg-light/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png?access-token=nr1yo2LitcA3V1WiGnpQNQTE2ooNfxu7xxHlxldA7OirWsWMyBSLgoSzyVksXpdG', {}).addTo(mymap);
      mymap.attributionControl.addAttribution("<a href=\"https://www.jawg.io\" target=\"_blank\">&copy; Jawg</a> - <a href=\"https://www.openstreetmap.org\" target=\"_blank\">&copy; OpenStreetMap</a>&nbsp;contributors");
console.log("Leaflet Map Loaded.")
```

I've tried fiddling around with the jQuery selector to different things such as `'mapid'` but currently I run into the issue of:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).setView is not a function
    at Object.success (getPHP.js:19)
    at c (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out.

In my ajax call, I changed:

```
if (result.status.name == "ok") {

            console.log("All recieved well.");
            $(mymap).setView(result['data']['latlng']);

}
```

to

```
if (result.status.name == "ok") {

            console.log("All recieved well.");
            mymap.setView(result['data']);

 }
```

Not sure why I was using a jQuery selector in the first place, but oh well you learn I suppose.